# My CSS animations are not working, while everything else is

Tags: html, css, node.js

I've been coding a website of mine, and I encountered this absolutely annoying problem!

My CSS animations, for my 404 page **aren't working**. All of the other style definitions work perfectly though, **EXCEPT** animations. This leads me to believe, that something is wrong with my CSS. If you need extra code, I'm willing to provide you it. My website is using **Node.JS** with a framework called **Express** to host the website. Again, the rest of the CSS works fine **EXCEPT** the animations. Here is the hellhole that is my CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Consolas';
    src: url("/fonts/consolas.woff") format("woff");
};

/* @keyframes slidein {
    0% {margin-top:50px;opacity:0;filter:blur(5px);}
    100% {margin-top:60px;opacity:1;filter:blur(0px);}
}; */
@keyframes slidein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
}

* {
    padding: 0 auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
    background-color: #232323;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Consolas';
}

.content {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.t404 {
    margin-top:50px;
    opacity:0;
    filter:blur(5px);
    font-size: calc(50pt + 2vmin);
    color: #00bcd9;
    animation: 1s ease-out slidein;
    -webkit-animation: 1s ease-out slidein;
}
.t404text {
    color: white;
}
```

Here's my HTML as well:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/style.css">
    <title>le testpage - 404</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <p class="t404">404</p>
        <p class="t404text">The page you were looking for was, unfortunately, not found.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: consider adding html and making a snippet, if the code is not TOO long

Comment: @WalidSiddik added the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keyframes definition is not being seen because you have a semi colon after the definition before.

Here it is without that ;

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Consolas';
  src: url("/fonts/consolas.woff") format("woff");
}


/* @keyframes slidein {
    0% {margin-top:50px;opacity:0;filter:blur(5px);}
    100% {margin-top:60px;opacity:1;filter:blur(0px);}
}; */

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

* {
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  background-color: #232323;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Consolas';
}

.content {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.t404 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  filter: blur(5px);
  font-size: calc(50pt + 2vmin);
  color: #00bcd9;
  animation: 1s ease-out slidein;
  -webkit-animation: 1s ease-out slidein;
}

.t404text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p class="t404">404</p>
  <p class="t404text">The page you were looking for was, unfortunately, not found.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:
I think the problem is that you are running your animation for just one second and also once. Try making its animation-iteration-count infinite.

```
@keyframes slidein {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.t404 {
    margin-top:50px;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    filter:blur(5px);
    font-size: calc(50pt + 2vmin);
    color: #00bcd9;
    animation: slidein 2s infinite ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: slidein 2s infinite ease-out;
}
```